# NextJs renders my route component 4 times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to learn NextJS v13.2.4. So I'm kinda trying things out and I noticed that my route components are getting rendered 4 times. I don't know if it's because of development mode or somthing else. So is it normal ?
Here's mo code :

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import React from "react";

const PortfolioProjectPage = () => {

  const router = useRouter();
  console.log(router.query);

  return <h1>PortfolioProjectPage</h1>;
};

export default PortfolioProjectPage;
```

and in the console I get this when I visit http://localhost:3000/portfolio/bridge route:

```
Object {  }                      [projectid].js:6:10
Object {  }                           bridge:1861:29
Object { projectid: "bridge" }   [projectid].js:6:10
Object { projectid: "bridge" }        bridge:1861:29
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is expected, see the detailed explanation here, and some possible methods for optimizing: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/12010

Answer (score 1):

actually would be twice , because it enabled StrictMode in dev

https://zh-hant.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I turn it off ?

Comment: in the next.config.js,  set reactStrictMode to false

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/react-strict-mode

Comment: actually not recommended cause StrictMode will check potential problems.